# Why can't I select IEEE logic ports in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am using the `circuitikz` package to create a diagram. I want to use the IEEE logic gates, so have added the following line: `\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}`. A full example is below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
  
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
    (0,0) node[nand port] (a) {}
    (-2,0) node[left] {$A$} node[circ,left] {} -| node[circ,midway]{} (a.in 1) -| (a.in 2)
    (a.out) to[short,-*] node[right] {$\neg A$} ++(5mm,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

However, the `\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}` line causes the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'ieee' unknown in choice key '/tikz/circuitikz/
logic ports'. I am going to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
```

I am using `circuitikz 2020/02/04` and `pgf 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)`. I have installed latex using the `texlive-full` package available on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

IEEE logic ports were added in [circuitikz version 1.1.0](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/releases/tag/v1.1.0) (2020-04-19). Update circuitikz to later version to use IEEE logic ports.